# Run Karma tests only on file change

Tags: karma-runner, jspm

Is it possible disable the initial execution of the karma test suite such that it is only executed when a watched file changes?

The problem with the initial run in my case is the following.
I am using the [jspm development bundling](http://jspm.io/0.17-beta-guide/development-bundling.html) which watches the files included inside the bundle for changes and incrementally rebuilds the bundle if such a change event is emitted.
Since this process runs forever, I cannot wait for it's termination and then launch Karma.
So I'm launching Karma and the bundling in parallel which works great except the initial run where no bundle exists or the bundle potentially contains old sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created the npm module called [wait-for-change](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-for-change).
Now I can use it inside the package.json like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "wait-for-change my-bundle.js && karma start"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "wait-for-change": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

This works pretty well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using grunt watch task. It will watch the changes and run the test.
You can search for boilerplate as well.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. But unfortunately using grunt is not an option for me. I'd like to have my workflow as lean as possible. Also I would prefer not to launch karma from an external process over and over again.